# Fatal error in ZF2, PHP7, MongoODMModule

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, php-7, doctrine-odm

I am new to ZF2/PHP7 and DoctrineMongoODM and am stuck with this issue. I have a working Skeleton app and am trying to add Doctrine to make some MongoDB reports. I've followed the installation instructions carefully but I can't figure out what's wrong. Could it be a bug in ZF2? Please let me know what you I think I might be doing wrong.

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule

**Fatal error:** Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DoctrineModule\ServiceFactory\AbstractDoctrineServiceFactory::canCreate() must be an instance of Interop\Container\ContainerInterface, instance of Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager given, called in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/ServiceFactory/AbstractDoctrineServiceFactory.php on line 69 and defined in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/ServiceFactory/AbstractDoctrineServiceFactory.php on line 40

Composer:
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"require": {
"php": ">=7.0",
"doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module": "dev-master",
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.6.2"
}

Comment: You will need to update your ZF2 to ZF3 if you plan on using the `dev-master` branch of ODM module. Alternatively you can use an earlier version of the module which supports ZF2 such as `0.*`.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  Thanks @AlexP